# gnuplot multiple histograms with both common and different keys

Tags: gnuplot, primary-key, histogram

I generated N column-stacked histograms but I'm facing issues with unique keys. The data file looks like:

```
Process_1 10 Process_1 20 Process_4 10 Process_1 10
Process_2 20 Process_4 35 Process_6 30 Process_2 10 
Process_3 30 Process_3 15 Process_1 20 Process_4 30
```

I'm using the following script:

```
set terminal png small size 1024,768
set out "outHistograms.png"
set style data histogram
set style fill solid border
set style histogram columnstacked
set boxwidth 0.6 relative
plot \
"data.csv" using 2:key(1) ,  \
"data.csv" using 4:key(3) ,  \  
"data.csv" using 6:key(5) ,  \
"data.csv" using 8:key(7)    \
```

As you can see, some keys are common across the different histograms, some others aren't.

The result is visible here:
http://s28.postimg.org/pzjk5egh9/exampl_hist.png
(sorry I can't include pictures to the post due to my recent subscription)

Problem:
Keys are duplicated and colours aren't unique to a key.

I would like to remove duplicates and to have an unique key (and colour) per process across all the histograms.

I've also tried the following with the same result:

```
plot \
newhistogram "a" lt 1 at 0, "data.csv" using 2:key(1),  \
newhistogram "b" lt 1 at 4, "data.csv" using 4:key(3)
```

I guess I need a way to 'tell' gnuplot that all odd columns need to be treated as a whole.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You want to have only five keys (Process_1,2,3,4,6) in five colours? The plot itself looks like you want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gnuplot cannot sort and identify your data, you need to have six rows for six keys (=processes).

```
Process_1 10 15 20
Process_2 10  0  0
Process_3 10 15 20
Process_4  0 35  0
Process_5  0  0  0
Process_6  0  0 20
```

Now you only plot the keys for the first iteration in column(2), and that`s it.

```
set style data histogram
set style fill solid border
set style histogram columnstacked
set boxwidth 0.6 relative
plot \
data using 2:key(1) ,  \
data using 3 ,  \  
data using 4 ,  \
```

P.S. Your data is not ".csv" (*comma separated values*). I just saved the file name in the string variable "data" here.

P.P.S. Please remove all decorations (plot title etc.) from your script before posting it here. Also the terminal settings are superflous. Unless the make a problem of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I now have the expected result.